# shouldOverrideUrlLoading Loading URL twice

Tags: android, webview

I'm using the the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading to add some headers to the webview. The problem is every link is loaded twice. First without the override and the through the override. How can I avoid this?

EDIT:

```
private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url==oldurl){
            return false;
        }
        else oldurl=url; if (url.contains("javascript")){
            return false;
        }
        else if (url.contains(url1)) {
               view.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
            return true;
        }
        else if (url.contains(url2)) {

            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your code.. without code we cant help you

Comment: Hi the code is been posted. Please take a look.